# Angularjs compile html without inserting into view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I have a page that contains of widgets.
Widget is object with settings & `templateUrl` where I bind these settings, so I build my page compiling these settings using `$compile` service via directive. This is how I render in view:

```
<div ng-repeat="widgetObj in myWidgets" compile="widgetObj">
    <div><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
</div>
```

When widget is compiled, it is added in the inner div instead of loading icon.

**Problem:**

I have to render html from `widgetObj` and send compiled html to server as string. One solution that I found was to compile widget as I normally do, but in hidden div and when it is compiled i take that HTML and send it. With this solution everything is fine (*mostly*), but the problem occurs when I want to render multiple pages (5+). My chrome starts freezing and memory usage goes 1,2 GB+.

I know that using `$compile` & working with DOM in controller is not the best solution, but for my task I need compiled html.

Hopefully you can suggest me something considering my problem or maybe give hint for a better solution. Currently I am looking forward to background workers, but not sure if it is even possible considering this approach.